# ServerCertificateValidationCallback reversal

Tags: c#, ssl, ssl-certificate

Due to some certificate issues, I had to write

```
ServicePointManager.ServerCertificateValidationCallback += (sender, certificate, chain, errors) => true;
```

Is this a better way to reverse it after the call has been made, or this is unnecessary?

```
var temp = ServicePointManager.ServerCertificateValidationCallback;
ServicePointManager.ServerCertificateValidationCallback += (sender, certificate, chain, errors) => true;

var r = func(obj);

ServicePointManager.ServerCertificateValidationCallback = temp;
```

Answer (score 1):

The whole operation should be wrapped in `try ... finally` to ensure that the original value gets restored even when exceptions are flying around. `+=` can be replaced with `=` unless some is using the callback for things other than validation (e.g. logging).

Of course, this scheme falls flat on its face in a concurrent situation. The thing should at least be put into a critical section or mutexed, so that problems manifest merely as poor performance instead of Heisenbugs...

Comment: I note that if the callback here is an *event* then the code generated by default for the event adder will do the appropriate low-lock algorithm to ensure that there are no lost additions. Of course if the callback here is just a delegate -- as it appears to be -- then yes, you're responsible for writing that code yourself.

Comment: @Eric: It's documented as being a delegate. However, even with events the reverse of operator `+=` is `-=`, not restoring some old - *and possibly stale* - state; this would make the scheme as safe as the operators themselves are (dropping `temp` entirely). Of course, `-=` is problematic because it requires 'materialising' (catching) the lambda for the `+=` to give it identity, and another complication comes from the fact that `var` doesn't work with lambdas in C#...